# Modelling L-0 norm of a vector

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, binary-variable, big-m

I have a binary variable $\bf x$ of length 4000.  Let
${\bf x}=[x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_{4000}]$.

Let's say we have ${\bf y}=[y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4]$, where
\begin{align}
y_1&=x_1+x_5+x_{9}+\cdots+x_{3997} \\
y_2&=x_2+x_{6}+x_{10}+\cdots+x_{3998} \\
y_3&=x_3+x_{7}+x_{11}+\cdots+x_{3999} \\
y_4&=x_4+x_{8}+x_{12}+\cdots+x_{4000}
\end{align}

Now, the constraint I have is: the number of nonzero elements in ${\bf y}$ is $\le 2$

In other words, the $l_0$ norm of vector ${\bf y}$ is $\le 2$

How to model this constraint with and without (if possible) introducing new variables?

With new variables $z_i$

$$y_i \leq M \cdot z_i \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, 3, 4$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{4} z_i \leq 2$$

Is it correct? If yes, what would be a good value for $M$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct and is the standard approach. You want $M$ to be a small upper bound on the left hand side when $z_i=1$, so take $M$ to be the number of $x$ variables on the right hand side of the equality constraint for $y_i$. In your example, that would be $M=1000$.

If $y$ does not appear anywhere else in your model, you can eliminate it by substitution, yielding constraints of the form $\sum_j x_j \le M z_i$, which you can optionally strengthen by disaggregating to $x_j \le z_i$.  The resulting formulation is essentially the same as in https://or.stackexchange.com/a/11785/500