# How to linearize this L0 norm of a vector?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization, combinatorial-optimization

I have an QP optimization problem.

$\bf x$ is the binary optimizaion variable of size $12\times 1$.

One of the constraints is non-linear/non-convex.

The constraint is L0 constraint.

The constraint I have is

$$[{\bf Ux}]_{l0}\le 2$$

here ${l0}$ denotes the L0 norm of the resulting vector.

$\bf U$ is given by

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

We can linearize the constraint by introducing new variables and adding big_M constraints.

But I need some solution that does not introduce new variables, but uses the matrix $\bf U$ structure.

RobPratt gave some solution here...https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11784/how-to-model-this-constraint-for-a-qp-problem/11785#11785

How can we model this particular constraint?

Can we define some Matrix that utilizes the characteristics of $\bf U$?

Any solution?

Comment: @RobPratt yes. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $3$-subset $\{x_i,x_j,x_k\}$ of variables that appear in three different rows, you want to enforce $$\lnot(x_i \land x_j \land x_k).$$  As in the linked answer, conjunctive normal form yields ($4^3=64$) linear constraints
$$x_i + x_j + x_k \le 2.$$
PORTA verifies that this formulation (including the bounds on $x$) is ideal.

Comment: would you please explain. What do you mean by *each 3
-subset {$x_i,x_j,x_k$} of variables*? In row one the variables $x_1,x_4,x_7,x_{10}$  appear. Similarly, in row 2, the variables $x_2,x_5,x_8,x_{11}$  appear.. and so on

Comment: Pick one variable from each row.  For example, $\{x_4,x_{11},x_3\}$ is one such $3$-subset.